# Custom properties file read as entity in lower project layers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I want to use my custom propertyclass.
My Project hiearcy like this,each are different project.

I can use ConfigurationProperties with Autowired annoation in mycontroller project but when I try it in my dao project that time autowired myproperties is null.

-MyController-->Autowired myproperties ok
-MyService

-MyDAO-->Autowired myproperties is null

```
 @Component 
//@Configuration
 @PropertySource("classpath:my.properties")
@ConfigurationProperties public class MyProperties {
```

I want to use my custom properties file as object in my lower layer projects.

In my dao layer I can read custom properties file  like key value,but I want to read it as entity.

```
  prop = new Properties();
            String filename = "my.properties";
            input = MyProperties.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
prop.load(input);

        Enumeration<?> e = prop.propertyNames();
        while (e.hasMoreElements()) {....
```

Comment: If I'm understand you problem correctly, you have an issue with accessing a resource from DAO artifact (jar file).
Try to add asterisk in the path of your prop file  "classpath*:some_path"

Comment: CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX  - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/ResourcePatternResolver.html#CLASSPATH_ALL_URL_PREFIX